# Is a Fine Art Baryta print suitable for display in an office with fluorescent lights?

Tags: prints, display, paper, fine-art, fluorescent

I am considering printing a color photo with prominent blacks and saturated colors to be mounted on a 75x50 panel for display in my office.
The office has two large windows on the wall adjacent to the one to which the panel will be mounted. Lighting is via fluorescent tubes.

My question: will I get many ugly reflections if I print it on fine-art baryta paper? Shall I go for a matte paper in this situation?

Comment: @mattdm yes I mean normal office fluorescent tubes, edited. Thanks!

Comment: Will there be a glass/plastic in front of the print?

Comment: @Francesco no, no glass, no protective layer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Baryta is a naturally occurring mineral technically known as barium sulfate. This snow white clay is used as a white pigment ingredient for paint. It is used as a brighter for art papers. Photo papers are coated with baryta to get increased whiteness and a higher reflectivity.

We view photo prints by reflected light from a nearby light source. Light plays on the print and transverses the dyes and pigments that comprise the image. This light then hits the baryta undercoat and is reflected back towards the viewer. Thus the illuminating light makes two transits thru the image on its way to the viewer.

The result is an enriched presentation of the artwork. The sheen and whiteness gives a pure white that keys off the tones and colors. The result is an increased perception of contrast and sharpness. The baryta coat enhances most artwork.

Comment: so your overall advice would be to use Baryta without fears of reflections?

Comment: That's my suggestion!  You can deal with reflections using a flat clear art protective paint spray or frame and cover with anti-reflection glass or plastic.